# How to use Camunda BPMN Send task and Receive Task

Tags: camunda

I am newbee in Camunda BPMN 2.0, i need help on how to implements and use send and receive task from one pool to another.

Answer (score 7):

Attach a JavaDelegate implementation to the send task:

```
<sendTask id="sendTask" camunda:class="org.camunda.bpm.MySendTaskDelegate" />
```

Inside the `MySendTaskDelegate`, correlate a message to the receive task in the other process instance:

```
public class MySendTaskDelegate implements JavaDelegate {

  public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

    execution.getProcessEngineServices()
      .getRuntimeService()
      .createMessageCorrelation("someMessage")
      .processInstanceBusinessKey("someBusinessKey")
      .correlate();

  }

}
```

This assumes, that

1. The waiting process instance has a businessKey of value `someBusinessKey`. The business key can be provided when starting the process instance.
2. The waiting process instance has a receive Task with a message name `someMessage`. The message name for a receive task can be specified in BPMN 2.0 xml using the `<message ... />` element. See: http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/bpmn20/#tasks-receive-task

Comment: Thanks meyerdan for your help!! Though am having an Error Server  "Error: Cannot instantiate process definition applicant_process:10:d09763fb-f6db-11e3-ad2a-8851fbcb5a9b: Cannot correlate message someMessage: No process definition or execution matches the parameters", Could you please explain to me how this commes about?

Comment: @ElvisWhizzkid Your receiver process is not executable. Go to the modeler and select the executable checkbox. Plus ignore the BusinessKey if you are not using any.